# Does Plaid development mode support webhook?

Tags: plaid

I'm using plaid-ruby, try to add user with webhook:

```
Plaid.add_user 'connect',
               params['username'],
               params['password'],
               params['bank_type'],
               params['pin'],
               {
                 list: params['list'],
                 login_only: true,
                 webhook: 'http://requestb.in/rrd6zbrr'
               }
```

But with no luck, don't get any requests to requestbin.

Does Plaid support webhooks in development mode? Or maybe requestb.in is blocked ?

Comment: Have a look at http://putsreq.com/, you could also simulate a validate expected response: "The response will contain a corresponding success message and code..."

Comment: I have reached out to Plaid support.  Will let you know if/when I receive a response.

Answer (score 5):

Plaid test environment does support webhooks. I reached out to Plaid support to ask specifically about [Plaid Link](https://github.com/plaid/link) since that is what I am using in my iOS app. Here is the response I received from Plaid:

> Plaid Link does support webooks. Below is some sample code to illustrate:

```
<button id='linkButton'>Open Plaid Link</button>
<script src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/stable/link-initialize.js"></script>
<script>
var linkHandler = Plaid.create({
  env: 'tartan',
  clientName: 'Test',
  key: 'test_key',
  product: 'connect',
  webhook: '[WEBHOOK URL]',
  onSuccess: function(public_token, metadata) {
    // Send your public_token to your app server here.
  },
});

// Trigger the Link UI
document.getElementById('linkButton').onclick = function() {
  linkHandler.open();
};
</script>
```

> Note that the product must be “connect” and that you must provide a webhook URL.

I was able to get webhooks working in my own environment (iOS client app, with Parse/Heroku backend), but I didn't use the test credentials - I used a real account. FYI, it took about 10 minutes between when I added the user and received a webhook back.

Comment: I had the issue where I originally created an invalid webhook when the user was "connected".  Despite issuing subsequent patch user requests to update the webhook ( and gettiing a code 4 ack ),  I never would receive any future webhook status updates for the user.    To resolve I had to delete  the user and re-connect with corrected webhook.  This should not be how it works.